# Autofac in ASP.net core 3.0+ DependencyResolutionExcp: for InstancePerRequest or InstancePerMatchingLifeTimeScope

Tags: autofac, asp.net-core-3.1

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

DependencyResolutionException: No scope with a tag matching '' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.

If you see this during execution of a web application, it generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario). Under the web integration always request dependencies from the dependency resolver or the request lifetime scope, never from the container itself.
Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetime.FindScope(ISharingLifetimeScope mostNestedVisibleScope)

DependencyResolutionException: Unable to resolve the type 'AutofacWebApplication.Service.TestService' because the lifetime scope it belongs in can't be located. The following services are exposed by this registration:
- AutofacWebApplication.Service.ITestService

Details
Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ScopeSelectionMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action next)

Stack
Query
Cookies
Headers
Routing

DependencyResolutionException: No scope with a tag matching '' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. If you see this during execution of a web application, it generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario). Under the web integration always request dependencies from the dependency resolver or the request lifetime scope, never from the container itself.
Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetime.FindScope(ISharingLifetimeScope mostNestedVisibleScope)
Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ScopeSelectionMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action next)

Comment: Cool, you posted an error message. Good job!

Comment: You won't get much help just by posting an error message - maybe you could add a question? The error message includes a probable cause:
> "If you see this during execution of a web application, it generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario)"

Have you checked that possibility? You might find [this article](https://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/) by the Autofac author useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Per the documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#differences-from-asp-net-classic):

> **Use InstancePerLifetimeScope instead of InstancePerRequest.** In previous ASP.NET integration you could register a dependency as `InstancePerRequest` which would ensure only one instance of the dependency would be created per HTTP request. This worked because Autofac was in charge of [setting up the per-request lifetime scope](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html). With the introduction of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, the creation of per-request and other child lifetime scopes is now part of the [conforming container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/) provided by the framework, so all child lifetime scopes are treated equally - there’s no special “request level scope” anymore. Instead of registering your dependencies `InstancePerRequest`, use `InstancePerLifetimeScope` and you should get the same behavior. Note if you are creating your own lifetime scopes during web requests, you will get a new instance in these child scopes.

To add to that - it means *also* don't use `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope` because, as you've seen, none will match.